# input_formats in Django ModelForm DateTimeInput throwing TypeError

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-forms, modelform

I have seen a lot of questions on this and all the answers seem to be because input_formats was incorrectly being placed on the DateTimeField on the model and not on the form. Well, I'm trying to do this on the ModelForm and I'm still getting an error. Can anyone see where I may be going wrong here?

**models.py**

```
class Vacancy(models.Model):
    deadline = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

**forms.py**

```
class CreateVacancyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Vacancy
        fields = ["deadline"]
        widgets = {
            "deadline": forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
                input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'], attrs={
                    'class': 'form-control'
                })
       }
```

The error:

```
 line 56, in Meta
    "deadline": forms.DateTimeInput(format='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'input_formats'
```

I am using Django version **3.1.1**

Comment: `DateTimeInput` widget does not has `input_formats` keyword. You may refer this : https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/forms/widgets/#datetimeinput

Comment: try my answer below. it works in my hand.

Comment: Hi, just curious if my answer below worked in your hand or not.

Comment: @ha-neul I think I tried your method and it didn't work but I have resolved the issue altogether now by deciding to simply use a DateField. There was no real need for me to use a DateTimeField.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
class CreateVacancyForm(ModelForm):
    deadline = forms.DateTimeField(input_formats=['%d/%m/%Y %H:%M'],
       widget = forms.DateTimeInput(
          format ='%d/%m/%Y %H:%M',
          attrs=  {'class':'form-control'}))

    class Meta:
        model = Vacancy
        fields = ["deadline"]
```

Here, we are matching DateTimeField's `input_formats` with DateTimeInput's `format`.